# Formdata is passing null value in req.body nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, backend, mern

I am passing a uploaded file through formdata from client to server, and the request by the server received has empty body. Here is the code, can someone please help?

Client side code -

[image]

Server side code -

[image]

[image]

OUTPUT -

browser console -

[image: browser console]

nodejs console -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a middleware like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to parse form-data

Answer (score 1):

Your content-type will be

> multipart/form-data

Not an application/json

Try to make something like this:
https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/react-file-upload-proper-server-side-nodejs-easy/